# Linq group by columns in a nested collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> rows = new List<List<object>
{
  //Columns
  new List<object> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }, 
  new List<object> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 },
  new List<object> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 },
  new List<object> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 } 
}
```

I basically want to group all the 10's, 20's, 30's, 40's, 50's.

I want to do it using Linq and in the best possible way. Please take into consideration that the size of my collection can go upto 20 million or more.

I was able to achieve it by doing the following however it gives me out of memory exception when I do a for each on the group collection.

```
 IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> rows = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<object> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }, 20000000);

 var group = rows.SelectMany(x => x.Select((InnerValue, Index) => new { Index, InnerValue })).GroupBy(x => x.Index);
```

**EXPECTED RESULT BELOW:**

```
var expectedResult = new List<List<object>
{
  new List<object> { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }, 
  new List<object> { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20 },
  new List<object> { 30, 30, 30, 30, 30 },
  new List<object> { 40, 40, 40, 40, 40 } 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please display what result should be? I don't exactly understand what results needs to be. Basically you want to extract columns?

Comment: `var allITems = rows.SelectMany(x=>x.Select((value, index) =>new {value, index}));
 var group1 =  allITems.Where(x=>x.index ==0);`

Comment: @Damith I dont see the difference between your code and mine, apart from the fact that you are simply creating 1 group of 10's.

Comment: Are you getting exception with my code? I haven't use group by..

Comment: @Damith no exception but the where statement is hard coded. I cannot know the size of my data therefore I cant do where (x => x.index == 0).

Comment: @Damith why is group by causing out of memory exception. its deferred execution.

Comment: Why Linq? This transformation is not natural for Linq, also cannot be deferred in general, so simply building iteratively `List<List<object>>` sounds like a good solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use linq :), you can do it with the following query:

```
    List<List<object>> expectedResult =
        rows.SelectMany(r => r)
        .ToLookup(k => k, v => v)
        .Select(kv => kv.ToList())
        .ToList();
```